# Lighting diagrams language and notation

Tags: software-recommendation, lighting, export, programming

I know, the use case might be specific but more and more stuff in all industry sectors is digitalized—and so is the communication between different departments which sometimes talk very different languages. I searched the internet, but I wasn't able to find a clear answer (either I didn't find the right search phrases or the internet itself just doesn't know).

Here's my scenario: I'm working with several departments which work with diagrams (for example a lighting setup). This diagram solves different purposes:

- which devices are used?
- where are they placed?
- where are they pointing?
- how are they configured (e.g. exposure)?

They tend to export their finalized diagram as either an image or a PDF— which is fine if you want to print it out but considerably less helpful if another department (mine) has to work with the raw information. That's where I wondered if there's some kind of industry standard (SVG, XML, JSON, etc.) which is both supported by the programs these departments used and can be interpreted by some sort of programming language. Do you know anything like that?

They might be integrated into floor plans also showing staging/blocking and/or camera setup.